# python:How to tell ide this value is a 'Baseprocess' element which from dict

Tags: python

```
dic = {}
ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')

def getProcessFromDict():
    for i in range(3):
       p :multiprocessing.context.SpawnProcess = dic[str(i)] p.
```

See the pic,ide dont know what type is the value
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBDaE.png)

```
def setProcessIntoDict():
    for i in range(3):
       p = ctx.Process(target=foo,
                    name="{}".format(i))
       p.start()
       print(type(p))
       dic[str(i)] = p
```

Comment: Please provide some context. What is the _actual_ problem that you are trying to solve? Which value? Which IDE? _**Why**_ do you need to tell the IDE that "*this value is a 'Baseprocess' element?*"? What are all the `p.` parts of your code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: check again ,pls